# Ef core is generating foreign keys without me telling it to do so

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am currently using fluent api to generate databases.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region Account
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Account");

            //Properties
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.Id)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasColumnType("INT")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.Code)
                .HasColumnName("Code")
                .HasColumnType("CHAR(4)")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.Desc)
                .HasColumnName("Desc")
                .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR(20)")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property(a => a.AccountTypeCode)
                .HasColumnName("AccountTypeCode")
                .HasColumnType("CHAR(1)")
                .IsRequired();

            //Primary Key
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasKey(a => a.Id);

            //Indexes
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasIndex(a => a.Code)
                .IsUnique();
            #endregion

            #region TxnLine
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().ToTable("TxnLine");

            //Properties
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.Id)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasColumnType("INT")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.TxnHeaderId)
                .HasColumnName("TxnHeaderId")
                .HasColumnType("INT")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.AccountCode)
                .HasColumnName("AccountCode")
                .HasColumnType("CHAR(4)")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.Seq)
                .HasColumnName("Seq")
                .HasColumnType("SMALLINT")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.Desc)
                .HasColumnName("Desc")
                .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR(100)")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.DebitCredit)
                .HasColumnName("DebitCredit")
                .HasColumnType("CHAR(1)")
                .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().Property(a => a.Amount)
                .HasColumnName("Amount")
                .HasColumnType("DECIMAL(12,2)")
                .IsRequired();

            //Primary Key
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>().HasKey(a => a.Id);

            //Check Constraints
            //
            //
            modelBuilder.Entity<TxnLine>(entity =>
                entity.HasCheckConstraint("CK_TxnLine_DebitCredit", "[DebitCredit] IN ('D','C')"));
            #endregion TxnLine
        }
```

As specified in the above code block, I did not tell ef core to generate TxnLine.AccountId, nor did I have any HasMany or HasOne relationships between TxnLine and Account.
Ef core seems to think (incorrectly) that I have a relationship between TxnLine and Account, and generated an AccountId foreign key on the TxnLine table for me.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuqDb.png)

However, I intended to use TxnLine.AccountCode as the 'soft link' between TxnLine and Account, and I do not want TxnLine to in anyway be dependent on Account.
What is this happening and is there a way to tell ef core to not create the unwanted TxnLine.AccountId?

Comment: Please add code for your entities.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It is because I have a navigation property in TxnLine (public Account Account {get;set;}). I removed it and now the TxnLine.AccountId is gone. Please post an answer so l can accept it. Cheers!

Comment: was glad to help! But I can't scrap enough for the answer - so I'm good =) But you can post your own - with model and comment what and why went "wrong" =)